# How can i dynamically synchronize a slider with the time of a mediaelement using MVVM and Windows store app?

Tags: timer, slider, windows-8.1, mvvm-light, mediaelement

i am developing a media player using MVVM Light and windows 8.1 store app.

I would like to synchronize my mediaelement with a slider so i can go to any part of my media just by interacting with the slider.

Here is how my slider is declared in my view :

```
<Slider Width="589" Height="102" Value="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding PosMax, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Here is how i manage my viewModel :

```
public class PlayerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  private readonly MediaElement _video;
  private readonly string _filename;
  private double _volume;
  private double _position;
  private double _posmax;
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private DispatcherTimer _timer = null;

public PlayerViewModel()
{
    _filename = "animal.mp4";
    _video = new MediaElement { AutoPlay = true };
    //don't load the stream until the control is ready
    _video.Loaded += VideoLoaded;
    _volume = 1;

}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
} 

public double Volume
{
    set
    {
        _volume = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Volume");
        _video.Volume = _volume;
    }
    get
    {
        return _volume;
    }
}

public double Position
{
    set
    {
        _position = (int) value;
        setMediaPostion(_position);
        OnPropertyChanged("Position");
    }
    get
    {
        return _position;
    }
}

public double PosMax
{
    set
    {
        _posmax = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("PosMax");
    }
    get
    {
        return _posmax;
    }
}

private void setMediaPostion(double _position)
{
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)_position);
    _video.Position = ts;
}

public MediaElement Video
{
    get { return _video; }
}

private async void VideoLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var file = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFileAsync(_filename);
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    _video.SetSource(stream, file.FileType);
    _posmax = (double)_video.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

}

If anyone has an idea, i'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

if your mediaElement is in xaml :

```
<MediaElement Name="media" Source="video.wmv"/>
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Width="589" Height="102" Value="{Binding Path=Position,ElementName=media}" />
```